# Passing a variable into a protected function in PHP

Tags: php, oop, variables

I am working with a plugin where there is a protected function like so

```
<?php

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

protected function get_user_id() {

              //If I manually enter a value here, the value passes along
      return ('myvariable'); 

   }
 }

?>
```

Yet when I make a variable like

```
<?php  $myvar = 'myvariable';  ?>
```

and try to insert it into the function like this

```
<?php

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

protected function get_user_id() {

              //If I use a variable, the value is lost
      return ($myvar); 

   }
 }

?>
```

it completely fails...
I am unfamiliar with protected classes and also how `return()` works so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried many lines of code such as

`print $myvar;` `return $myvar;` `echo $myvar;` with and without `()`

Comment: Try adding `global $myvar;`under your class

Comment: This has nothing to do with protected classes, it's just plain ordinary variable scope. Global variables can't be accessed inside a function unless you declare them with `global`.

Comment: @ElefantPhace Make that an answer

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't** introduce global state via the `global` keyword. You'll be welcoming a world of pain down the line.

Instead, inject the dependency (*the value, a user ID in this case*) into the class when it's created, or with a setter.

```
class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler
{

    private $user_id;

    protected function get_user_id()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    // setter injection; the value is
    // passed via the method when called
    // at any time
    public function set_user_id($user_id)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    // constructor injection; the value is
    // passed via the constructor when a new
    // instance is created
    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        $this->set_user_id($user_id);
    }

}
```

Then when you have an instance of this class:

```
// creates and sets $user_id = 42
$customUploadHandler = new CustomUploadHandler(42);

// sets $user_id = 77
$customUploadHandler->set_user_id(77);
```

Comment: This is a lot to digest...I am still trying to understand classes in php.

Comment: @VIDesignz I would recommend you pick up a good book on OOP then (*and **not** one exclusively for PHP*) While daunting at first, the above code is reasonably straightforward. Every `CustomUploadHandler` has inside of it a variable named `$user_id`. The functions `get`/`set_user_id` either return or assign to that value. This lets the object carry the value around with it, rather than having to "magically" reference the value from global scope.

Answer (score 0):

`Protected` means that only the class itself, the parent class and the childs of the class where the function is defined can use the function. So it depends from where you call the function for it to work. return statements without brackets should be fine.

Comment: What does this have to do with trying to use a global variable inside the function?

Comment: Thanks razhial, it doesnt answer my question but the knowledge is very helpful! :)

Comment: @Barmar: theres nothing about global variables in his question. actually to use global statement here is absolute nonsense. so i provided an answer to his "problems" which he mentioned: ("it completely fails... I am unfamiliar with protected classes and also how return() works so any help would be greatly appreciated.")

Comment: Read his code. He assigns the variable `$myvar` outside the function, then tries to return it inside the function. That's a global variable. Yes, you answered the question, but it was a non sequitor because he didn't know enough to ask the right question.

Comment: He assigns a variable. and has a function where this variable should be returned..now..how does this make the variable global? Take a look at Dan Luggs answer. Thats the way he should solve his problem.